# Fastest Way to Sort Large Vector of Data in Clojure

Tags: sorting, clojure

I need to be able to store data from a collection in such a way that the average value of any given set of keys is no greater than a specific number.

For example, let's say the average value of ":num" for any given set of 3 cannot be greater than or equal to 10, and I have the following set:

```
(def my-set
    ({:num 0}
     {:num 0}
     {:num 0}
     {:num 5}
     {:num 5}
     {:num 5}
     {:num 10}
     {:num 10}
     {:num 10}
))
```

In this collection, the last 3 hashes could not remain adjacent to one another because the average of them would be 10, but it would be fine to re-organize the collection like so, because the average for any given 3 would be 5:

```
(def my-set
        ({:num 0}
         {:num 5}
         {:num 10}
         {:num 0}
         {:num 5}
         {:num 10}
         {:num 0}
         {:num 5}
         {:num 10}
    ))
```

My question is, assuming this collection is much much larger than just this sample of 9 entries, possibly millions, and the total average of the ENTIRE collection is 5 or less, what would be the fastest and most efficient way to sort these so that the average of any 3 (or 10 or 100, or any given sample size) never reaches 10?

Here is my psuedocode solution that I feel would be way too slow:

1) Sort collection by value of :number 
2) Divide collection by 2 and split at the number of that index
3) Interleave first collection with reverse order of second collection.

So first collection would look like:

```
({:num 0} {:num 0} {:num 0} {:num 5})
```

And second collection (reversed):

```
({:num 10} {:num 10} {:num 10} {:num 5} {:num 5))
```

With interleave, resulting collection would be:

({:num 0} {:num 10} {:num 0} {:num 10} {:num 0} {:num 10} {:num 5} {:num 5} {:num 5})

There's got to be a better way to do it.

Comment: is your possible number values set limited by a known items? like in your example `#{0 5 10}` or there could be arbitrary numbers in the collection (i mean do you have some known constraints, or just some random input collection) ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

```
(def data-9
  [{:num 0}
   {:num 0}
   {:num 0}
   {:num 5}
   {:num 5}
   {:num 5}
   {:num 10}
   {:num 10}
   {:num 10}] )

(def data-11
  (into (vec data-9)
    [{:num 0}
     {:num 10}] ))

(defn interleave-by
  [data group-size]
  (let [data-num       (count data)
        part-size      (quot data-num group-size)
        leftover-num   (- data-num (* part-size group-size))
        data-sorted    (sort-by :num data)
        data-leftover  (take leftover-num data-sorted)
        data-use       (drop leftover-num data-sorted)
        data-parts     (partition-all part-size data-use)
        data-reordered (apply mapcat vector data-parts)
        data-final     (reduce into (vec data-leftover) data-reordered)
        ]
    data-final ))

(newline)
(println (interleave-by data-9 3))

data-num => 
9
part-size => 
3
leftover-num => 
0
data-sorted => 
({:num 0}
 {:num 0}
 {:num 0}
 {:num 5}
 {:num 5}
 {:num 5}
 {:num 10}
 {:num 10}
 {:num 10})
data-leftover => 
()
data-use => 
({:num 0}
 {:num 0}
 {:num 0}
 {:num 5}
 {:num 5}
 {:num 5}
 {:num 10}
 {:num 10}
 {:num 10})
data-parts => 
(({:num 0} {:num 0} {:num 0})
 ({:num 5} {:num 5} {:num 5})
 ({:num 10} {:num 10} {:num 10}))
data-reordered => 
({:num 0}
 {:num 5}
 {:num 10}
 {:num 0}
 {:num 5}
 {:num 10}
 {:num 0}
 {:num 5}
 {:num 10})
data-final => 
[[:num 0]
 [:num 5]
 [:num 10]
 [:num 0]
 [:num 5]
 [:num 10]
 [:num 0]
 [:num 5]
 [:num 10]]
(interleave-by data-9 3) => 
[[:num 0]
 [:num 5]
 [:num 10]
 [:num 0]
 [:num 5]
 [:num 10]
 [:num 0]
 [:num 5]
 [:num 10]]
```

It is harder if there is not an integer multiple of the group-size. This causes extra complexity involving `data-leftover`

```
(newline)
(println (interleave-by data-11 3))


data-num => 
11
part-size => 
3
leftover-num => 
2
data-sorted => 
({:num 0}
 {:num 0}
 {:num 0}
 {:num 0}
 {:num 5}
 {:num 5}
 {:num 5}
 {:num 10}
 {:num 10}
 {:num 10}
 {:num 10})
data-leftover => 
({:num 0} {:num 0})
data-use => 
({:num 0}
 {:num 0}
 {:num 5}
 {:num 5}
 {:num 5}
 {:num 10}
 {:num 10}
 {:num 10}
 {:num 10})
data-parts => 
(({:num 0} {:num 0} {:num 5})
 ({:num 5} {:num 5} {:num 10})
 ({:num 10} {:num 10} {:num 10}))
data-reordered => 
({:num 0}
 {:num 5}
 {:num 10}
 {:num 0}
 {:num 5}
 {:num 10}
 {:num 5}
 {:num 10}
 {:num 10})
data-final => 
[{:num 0}
 {:num 0}
 [:num 0]
 [:num 5]
 [:num 10]
 [:num 0]
 [:num 5]
 [:num 10]
 [:num 5]
 [:num 10]
 [:num 10]]
(interleave-by data-11 3) => 
[{:num 0}
 {:num 0}
 [:num 0]
 [:num 5]
 [:num 10]
 [:num 0]
 [:num 5]
 [:num 10]
 [:num 5]
 [:num 10]
 [:num 10]]
```

Comment: Thank you kindly! I just realized there is some major flaw in my logic of solving my algorithm, but I believe this information will come in handy in the future.

Answer (score 0):

- This is about the algorithm, and only incidentally to do with
  Clojure.
- What's required isn't sorting as such. We are looking for a
  permutation of the data such that no adjacent three (or however many)
  numbers average to five or more. We can map to the numbers before we
  derive the permutation.
- There need be no solution. For example, if any number is more than 
  fifteen, there isn't one.
- This looks similar to the [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem). It might well be that
  an exact solution is intractable, but a greedy or other approach will
  be practical.

I suggest you try the problem on the [Computer Science site](https://cs.stackexchange.com/).